# How to get the ID of selected record in the SQLite

Tags: c#, android-sqlite

I have list of records which is shown from app table using the Sqlite.

Here is code for List view.

```
            <ListView x:Name="registerlist" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding name}" Tapped="TextCell_Tapped"
                      Detail="{Binding email}">
                    </TextCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

As you can see I have "Tapped" property.

What I want to do is when tapped - update this record.

Here I started updating the record.

```
  public static void TextCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {

           //capture the record ID
           var recID = 



        }
    }
```

First thing I want to do is save the variable ID of "Tapped" record.
So when user tap's the record - How I can display Alert the ID of that specific Tapped record.

Comment: Are you getting the ID when you query SQLite?

Comment: This is what I need help with. I have a Model called "UserRegister" and I have public strings get and set for ID, name, email etc. The listview show records from UserRegister table. Now, the user tap one record, I want to save the ID of selected into a variable. I want hep with that.